Unable to preview the Expo React Native app built at github codespace using Expo Go app on my android phone
I am a student and I started learning React Native and Expo a day ago using a JSmastery's latest (as of now) Aora app tutorial.
I use Github Codespace for coding. Due to the difference in the network (i.e. becuase codespace and my mobile app is in a different network), I am unable to preview the Expo React Native app built at github codespace using Expo Go app on my android phone.
I have encountered the following error:
Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /172.**.*.*(port 8081) from 192.***.*.* (port 49***) after 100000ms: isConected failed: ETIMEDOUT (connection timed out)
I found and tried alternatives like but they were deprecated:
"expo login"  "npx install -g expo cli"
Turns out they were deprecated and it is asking me to step down my node version. I am seeking for an alternative using which I can simply preview my app in my phone or my laptop itself while still using github codespace for my coding process. Any ideas or suggestion would be really useful.

Start. your project in Codespaces with npx expo start --tunnel, than scan your the QR code with your android device.
